# Conditional callback with request sub domain. is it possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I tried something like this

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  before_action :something, if: request.subdomain == "specific"


end
```

but here i could not access request object and it throwing error.

```
undefined local variable or method `request' for SomeController:Class
```

Can someone suggest me how i can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use proc,

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  before_action :something, if: proc { |c| c.request.subdomain == "specific" }


end
```

Comment: helps alot. Thanks. can you explain which Class object does `c` contains here??

Comment: c is somecontroller's object instance

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like these

```
before_action :something

def something
  if request.subdomain == "specific"
   your code
  end
end
```

Comment: nope, in my case it's not possible as `:something` is a callback from a gem.